# JavaDoc like framework for shell scripts?

Tags: documentation, shell

Is there an open source or public domain framework that can document shell scripts similar to what JavaDoc produces? I don't need to limit this just to a specific flavor of shell script, ideally I would like a generic framework for documenting API or command line type commands on a web page that is easy to extend or even better is self documenting.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Perl, [here](http://bahut.alma.ch/2007_08_01_archive.html) is an example of someone who used Perl's POD system for documentation of a shell script.

> The trick is to have the Perl POD section in a bash "Here-Document", right after the null command (no-op) `:`.
>
> - Start with `: <<=cut`
> - Write your POD-formatted man page
> - That's it. Your POD ends with `=cut`, which has also been defined as the end of the shell Here-doc
>
> Your script can then be processed with all the usual Perl tools like perldoc, or perl2html, and you can even generate real man pages with pod2man.
>
> As an example, here is the `podtest.sh` script:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/dash
>
> echo This is a plain shell script
> echo Followed by POD documentation
>
> : <<=cut
> =pod
> =head1 NAME
>
>    podtest.sh - Example shell script with embedded POD documentation
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> No rights Reserved
>
> =cut
> ```
>
> To add this podtest.sh to your man pages:
>
> ```
>  pod2man podtest.sh >/usr/local/share/man/man1/podtest.sh.1
> ```

Comment: It's good to include an excerpt, in case the original disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Although Doxygen doesn't support bash script files, you **can** [make Doxygen work with bash](http://rickfoosusa.blogspot.nl/2011/08/howto-have-doxygen-support-bash-script.html)

If you don't mind the docs being separate to the code you definitely should check out [ronn](http://rtomayko.github.io/ronn/).

You might also find [Shocco](http://rtomayko.github.io/shocco/) useful, even though it's not the same as JavaDoc (the code is an integral part of the docs).

Answer (score 0):

You might consider [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/).  While it's mostly used to document C-ish languages like JavaDoc, you can probably come up with a setup that will work for shell scripts with a bit of wrangling.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method of documented shell scripts is to use troff and in script comments similar to C. Though I would suggest using the "Here-Document" method from Steve's post if your really need something that would be more extensible to embed either your troff/pod/rdoc/jdoc code.